# Nginx wildcard subdomain redirect while keeping query string

Tags: nginx

I am trying to redirect a wildcard subdomain to a new URL while appending the subdomain at the end of the URL; for example `sub1.example.com` would redirect to `www.newdomain.example/categories/sub1`:

```
server {
server_name ~^(.*)\.example\.com$ ;
return 301 $scheme://newdomain.example/categories/;
}
```

I thought Nginx by default would add this since there is no `?` at the end stopping it.

Answer (score 4):

Or without using the evil if:

```
server {
  server_name ~^(.*)\.example\.com$;
  return 301 $scheme://www.newdomain.example/categories/$1$request_uri;
}
```

as $request_uri already contains the query string / the arguments, see http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html

and I also want to mention the $is_args $args pair, when you don't want to use $request_uri

```
  location = /from {
    return 301 /to$is_args$args;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

See `server_name` examples in [official docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html):

```
server {
  server_name ~^(.*)\.example\.com$;
  if ($query_string) {
    return 301 $scheme://newdomain.example/categories/$1?$query_string;
  }
  return 301 $scheme://newdomain.example/categories/$1;
}
```

> sub1.example.com would redirect to www.newdomain.example/categories/sub1

`www.newdomain.example` or `example.com` which is correct?

Comment: Instead of the `if` directive, you can also use [`$is_args`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_is_args) as in  `return 301 $scheme://domain.com/categories/$1$is_args$args;`

Answer (score 0):

To redirect `http://cat.example.com/post/1?comments=true` to `http://example.com/categories/cat/post/1?comments=true`, you can use this configuration:

```
server {
    server_name ~^(.*)\.(example\.com)$;
    return 301 $scheme://$2/categories/$1$request_uri;
}
```

It uses regexes with capture groups from [`server_name`](http://nginx.org/r/server_name) to avoid duplication. The query string is not kept by default in your example and in the proposed configuration it is retained using [`$request_uri`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_request_uri):

```
$request_uri
    full original request URI (with arguments)
```